# Integration of $q in scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, q

I've read on several places that $q is gracefully integrated in scope in Angular JS.
Suppose that you have this:

```
var superService = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(['foo', 'bar']);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Of course, $q is useless here but if I use $timeout or run a $http call, the result is the same.

If I do this:

```
superService().then(function(data) {
    $scope.result = data;
});
```

It's ok. But if I do that:

```
$scope.result = superService();
```

It's also supposed to be ok. But in my case, $scope.result contains 3 elements (they are visible in my template with a ng-repeat): "then", "catch" and "finally" functions, I guess... instead of ['foo', 'bar'] of course.

My concrete example:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('HelloWorld', function($q, $timeout) { 
    var getMessages = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(['Hello', 'world']);
      return deferred.promise;
    };    
    return {
      getMessages: getMessages
    };  
  })  
  .controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {
    $scope.messages = HelloWorld.getMessages();
    //HelloWorld.getMessages().then(function(data) {
    //  $scope.messages = data;
    //}); 
  });
```

Any idea here?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: I'm familiar with what he's running into--see my answer--and it's a perfectly valid, if mildly unclear from a quick glance, question.

Comment: I see a problem here. A problem leads to question. Read the problem is like read the question... At least one person seems to have understood my problem: it's solved ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic promise unwrapping has been deprecated and will soon be removed. See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

Comment: Thanks! the former explains the latter :)